# Debugging curses app on windows

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm, curses, pdb

Is there a way to debug a python program, preferably from PyCharm?

I get the following error:

```
"C:\Program Files\Python27\python.exe" "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 3.1.3\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py" --multiproc --client 127.0.0.1 --port 63705 --file D:/prg/curlog/curlog.py awerun.log
pydev debugger: process 7988 is connecting

Connected to pydev debugger (build 135.973)

Redirection is not supported.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Redirection is not supported in PDCurses because it operates below the file handle level. Whether that means you can't debug is another question; I can only tell you that message comes from PDCurses.